# Map "RABBIT" string to call new "RABBIT"()

Tags: c++, string, oop, object, mapping

I have to populate my `grid` with rabbits, squirrels, wolfs, and cheetahs. I am looking for a mapping of string to type object

```
populate("CHEETAH", 2);
populate("WOLF", 3);
populate("SQUIRREL", 10);
populate("RABBIT", 10);
```

At the moment, I have this repetitive code that I would like to get rid of.

```
CELL grid[GRIDHEIGHT][GRIDWIDTH];

void populate()
{
    int num_rabbits = 0, num_squirrels = 0, num_wolves = 0, num_cheetahs = 0;
    int random, randX, randY;
    srand((int)time(NULL));

    while (num_rabbits < 10)
    {
        randX = rand() % GRIDHEIGHT;
        randY = rand() % GRIDWIDTH;

        if (!(grid[randX][randY].Has_An_Animal()))
        {
            grid[randX][randY].animal = new RABBIT();
            num_rabbits++;
        }
    }

    while (num_squirrels < 10)
    {
        randX = rand() % GRIDHEIGHT;
        randY = rand() % GRIDWIDTH;

        if (!(grid[randX][randY].Has_An_Animal()))
        {
            grid[randX][randY].animal = new SQUIRREL();
            num_squirrels++;
        }
    }

    while (num_wolves < 3)
    {
        randX = rand() % GRIDHEIGHT;
        randY = rand() % GRIDWIDTH;

        if (!(grid[randX][randY].Has_An_Animal()))
        {
            grid[randX][randY].animal = new WOLF();
            num_wolves++;
        }
    }

    while (num_cheetahs < 2)
    {
        randX = rand() % GRIDHEIGHT;
        randY = rand() % GRIDWIDTH;

        if (!(grid[randX][randY].Has_An_Animal()))
        {
            grid[randX][randY].animal = new CHEETAH();
            num_cheetahs++;
        }
    }
}//end
```

Comment: To clarify, you want to create a populate function creates objects of the type used as a parameter?

Comment: Yes, sorry for lack of detail. populate("RABBIT", 2), should create 2 RABBIT. Really, I'm just looking for some way to condense this code elegantly by using some mapping of string to object.

Comment: Does it have to be `populate("RABBIT", 2);` and not, say, `populate([](){return new RABBIT();}, 2);`?

Comment: **WARNING**: Using [`rand()` is considered harmful](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful) and you’re strongly encouraged to use an appropriate [random number generator facility in the Standard Library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) that produces actually random values. Your use of `time(NULL)` as a random number seed means that this will produce identical results if run in the same second, and on many platforms `rand()` is *barely* random at all.

Comment: @immibis I'd much rather prefer the former, as its readable and much more applicable IMO, but I'm open to anything. The latter makes me curious as well.

Comment: @tadman I will look into that. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think an easy way to go about this would be implementing a template function.

```
template <typename T>
void populate(int maxPop) {
    int i = 0;

    while (i < maxPop)
    {
        randX = rand() % GRIDHEIGHT;
        randY = rand() % GRIDWIDTH;

        if (!(grid[randX][randY].Has_An_Animal()))
        {
            grid[randX][randY].animal = new T();
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

And then to call the function with appropriate type simply:

```
populate<RABBIT>(10);
```

Comment: I looked at your solution, looked back at mine, and laughed. This is perfect! I totally overlooked templates. Thank you!

Comment: I have the same problem, I always have to ask myself if the basics would work for my situation.